# how do i compactly (without listing every index value) use a list when formatting a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, format, iteration

```
values =[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", "9", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",
         " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",]




outGrid = ("""
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
--------   --------   --------
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
--------   --------   --------
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
""" % (values))
```

Im making a sudoku game and cannot figure out a way to insert the values from the list into the grid with typing 'values' 81 times with all the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert `values` to a tuple:

```
outGrid = ("""
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
--------   --------   --------
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
--------   --------   --------
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
%s %s %s | %s %s %s | %s %s %s
""" % tuple(values))

print(outGrid)

         |          |      
         |          |      
         |          |      
--------   --------   --------
         |          |      
         |     9    |      
         |          |      
--------   --------   --------
         |          |      
         |          |      
         |          |
```